# In Redshift, what is the difference between size and pct_used in svv_table_info?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift, data-warehouse

For a single node dc2 redshift 160gb cluster, I checked different tables in my warehouse. Across most of the tables, I see that the pct_used (percent used)*cluster size doesn't match the numbers in size column. The pct_used always under-reports by a ratio of around 2-2.5; What could be the reason behind this? Does size include uncompressed size but pct_used is the actual compressed data size? In such case, sum(size) can cross the cluster size?